# Identifying a Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

Can any one please help me how to identify a given a website is a word press based or not ?

For example: flashnewstoday.com

Comment: View the source, dude: <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.0.2" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That website has the following in the header:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.0.2" />
```

You can also try accessing WordPress-specific URLs, like http://flashnewstoday.com/wp-login.php

Answer (score 1):

i usually just go to view-source and look for path that includes wp-content, and if it does most likely its wordpress powered.  seems like flashnewstoday.com is wp powered

also this:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.0.1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to 100% identify the back end of a web site. It could be being typed by a team of monkeys. There may be clues in various bits of HTML, but they may be wrong or misleading - I can make a Django web page output the same tags that others on here say identify a WordPress site.

Why do you want to know?

Comment: Very few sites are going to go to the trouble to mask it that heavily, though.

Comment: If I knew people were actively seeking out WordPress sites in order to exploit zero-day vulnerabilities, I would!

Answer (score 0):

If the core WordPress engine has not been modified, the simplest way is to look for an HTML element like this:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.0.1" />
```

The version number may be different, so just checking if the `content` attribute contains the string "WordPress" should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for

`<meta name="generator" content="WordPress x.x.x" />`

is not a sure fire way to tell the site is WP. There are plugins and WP functions that remove that tag in the interest of some "security through obscurity."

Look for directories like /wp-content/  and  /wp-content/plugins/

And look for a CSS file at
http://mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/somethemename/style.css and view that file for info on the theme itself.